# Floating Action Button Android Studio does not show me background color and image in preview

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am new to android. I am trying to learn Floating action button.
I was following this video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cASXtRa6yDc) .

But my preview does not show + icon and not the background color which I have applied in my code as you can see. When i run my project on an actual device it displays both image and background color. But not in my android preview.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Preview**

[Screenshot of my preview in android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6ibS.jpg)

Build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
}
```

**My Configuration**

1. Android Studio: 3.6.1

Android Studio 3.6.1

```
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897, built on February 27, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
```

I don't know for sure but could be related to [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1046)

Comment: try clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I loved that you are trying to help. But It didn't work. I think this is a bug as I suggested in my post. I think I should switch to stable version of Android Studio.

Comment: maybe try to update android studio. I think I had the same problem.

Comment: @mmdrezabaqalpour Currently which version are you using?

Comment: I am using the 4.2 canary version.

Comment: It worked. The redenring error has been fixed in android 4.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bug in Android Studio version you are using.

You can try the latest updated version to resolve this error.

**Update Android Studio**

```
Android Studio > Menu bar > Help>check for updates.
```